# Final compiling of achemso style package for publication - MolPharm

Tags: achemso

I have started using LaTeX to write draft manuscripts and now intend to submit an article to ACS - Molecular Pharmaceutics. The achemso class uses the keyval system, hence I provide 'mpohbp' as key. I am insecure about the fact that the draft does not look at all like final prints in the paper, which is different compared to e.g., the elsevier.cls class.

I believe the whole article will be reformatted for the final print and my article will not look like I have submitted it. Also I imagine that ACS MolPharm will be very inexperienced with LaTeX submissions. I want to avoid that my article does not look like a typical MolPharm/ACS article, just because I chose a LaTeX submission.

1. To what extent will my article be reformatted?
2. To what extent can I influence the final layout?
3. Does anyone have experience with doing LaTeX submissions at MolPharm?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

The ACS do not use LaTeX for final typesetting. Instead, articles are converted to PDF and are then typeset from this as a source (likely via another intermediate form). Different journal editorial offices take some different lines on what they expect in the submission in terms for formatting, but the typesetters do not really mind: it is all handled centrally.